# am having difficulty loading/rendering a very simple VRML model in three.js

Tags: three.js

Here is a very simple handmade VRML file. It represented a box. The VRML loader example code is not loading/rendering it corrected. It shows only two sides, whereas there should be six. Your help is appreciated.

Best,

Oldman

```
#VRML V2.0 utf8

Group {
  children
    Shape {
      appearance
      Appearance {
        material
        Material {
          diffuseColor  0 0.5  0.5
          specularColor 0 0.5  0.5
        }
      }
      geometry
      IndexedFaceSet {
        coord
        Coordinate {
          point [

          0 0 0,
          0 20 0,
          10 20 0,
          10 0 0,
          0 0 0,
          0 20 50,
          10 20 50,
          10 0 50,
          0 0 50,
          0 20 50,
          0 20 0,
          0 0 0,
          0 0 50,
          10 20 50,
          10 20 0,
          10 0 0,
          10 0 50,
          0 20 0,
          10 20 0,
          10 20 50,
          0 20 50,
          0 0 0,
          10 0 0,
          10 0 50,
          0 0 50
          ]
        }
        coordIndex [
            1,2,4,-1,
            2,3,4 -1,
            6,5,8 -1,
            6,8,7 -1,
            17,19,18,-1,
            17,20,19,-1,
            21,22,23,-1
            21,23,24,-1
            13,15,16,-1,
            13,14,15,-1,
            9,10,11,-1
            9,11,12
            ]
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the winding order of the faces is not consistent. You can workaround the issue by setting the `side` property of the objetc's material to `THREE.DoubleSide`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by winding number in this very simple example. But......this model has been hand constructed carefully. 6 faces, each composed of 2 triangles. Each triangle is properly oriented - ie: normal-vector given by the right-hand-rule points outwards for each triangle. So, back-face culling (if it is happening) should not make a front-pointing triangle disappear. Yet, triangles that should be visible are missing. I understand your "doublesided material" workaround. But why is that needed? ......Best....Oldman

Comment: I'm not sure. I did not have the time to study the triangle definition in more detail. Can you try to import your asset into Blender and export it to VRML again? Is it then possible to correctly render the cube in `three.js`?

Comment: Turns out that one face was wrongly oriented. But the rendering is wrong even after correcting those 2 triangles. I've been validating my VRML models against an application called FreeCAD, built by the OpenCascade people. My corrected model renders perfectly there. (I find Blender very confusing to use :):). How do I include the corrected VRML model and pictures in my next communication? Comments are probably not the right place for such inclusions.  BTW, I'm facing missing triangles in many of my VRML models. Just using this one as the simplest example. @Mugen87

Comment: How about sharing your corrected model via Google Drive or a similar service? BTW: The [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) might be a better place for ongoing discussions/investigations.

Comment: Thanks, will do that. And, I've been meaning to ask you how to post to the three.js forum. I've created an account and I show up in the forum, but it does not let me create a new topic or reply or any kind of entry.  @Mugen87

Comment: What is your user name in the forum?

Comment: oldman @Mugen87

Comment: I have raised your trust level by 1. You should now be able to post.

Comment: Still not able to either activate the "+New Topic" or the Reply buttons.  @Mugen87

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain myself why it does not work. You have the same trust level like other new users.